# Is this mixed ANOVA correctly specified in R?

Tags: r, anova, repeated-measures

I am trying to test some results I have for significance. It has been recommended that I use R and I am completely new to this.

#### Set-up:

- Groups: two groups of 8 subjects (16 total)
- Two conditions: alert and passive
- Measurements: responses for three different stimuli (A, B, and C) measured in each condition

#### Experiment: Testing the order of conditions

- Group one: Alert A, B and C followed by Passive A, B, and C
- Group two: Passive A, B, and C followed by Alert A, B, and C

Stimuli A, B and C are randomly interleaved in the experiment, does this matter in my ANOVA?

I am interested in making a between and within group comparison of responses to A, B, and C

#### Here is what I am doing:

My data is arranged in the following way

```
Group Subject Condition Stimulus  Response
One      S1    Alert          A    _Value_
One      S1    Alert          B    _Value_
One      S1    Alert          C    _Value_
One      S1    Passive        A    _Value_
One      S1    Passive        B    _Value_
One      S1    Passive        C    _Value_
One      S2    Alert          A    _Value_
...

Two      S9    Alert          A     _Value_
Two      S9    Alert          B     _Value_
Two      S9    Alert          C     _Value_
...
```

This is the code I used:

```
My_anova = aov(Response ~ Condition * Stimulus * Group + 
           Error(Subject/Condition * Stimulus ), data=My_Data)
```

#### Question

- Is this model correctly specified in R?

Comment: Welcome to the site. I've edited your question to remove the ANCOVA component as it seems quite distinct. I suggest you ask a second question regarding the ANCOVA component and provide a link to the current question in your ANCOVA question.

Answer (score 1):

It's very close.

```
My_anova = aov( Response ~ Condition * Stimulus * Group + 
           Error( Subject/(Condition * Stimulus) ), data = My_Data )
```

Comment: Thank you very much! From what I can tell, parenthesis have been added. What does this change in terms of grouping/the ANOVA model?

Comment: Run both commands and you'll find out.  You're not going to break anything trying stuff out.