# How to perform ANCOVA on mixed experimental design where covariate is one level of a condition using R?

Tags: r, repeated-measures, ancova

This is a second question related to previous post:
[Is this mixed ANOVA correctly specified in R?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16641/is-this-mixed-anova-correctly-specified-in-r)

To reiterate, the setup is as follows:

- Groups: two groups of 8 subjects (16 total)
- Two conditions: alert and passive
- Measurements: responses for three different stimuli (A, B, and C) measured in each condition

Experiment: Testing the order of conditions

- Group one: Alert A, B and C followed by Passive A, B, and C
- Group two: Passive A, B, and C followed by Alert A, B, and C

#### New Question:

- If I wanted to use the responses measured in the passive condition as a co-variate to the alert responses, how would I perform an ANCOVA analysis in R?

I am not sure how to handle this considering the repeated factors and between subject measures.